# Save aspx page as jpeg and send it as email in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, jpeg

My aspx page has a certificate image where i can type in name subject and grade. i want to send this aspx page as the body of the mail in jpeg format. so when the mail recepient receives the mail he should be able to view the certificate and download it. Please help.

here is my aspx page

```
<body id="bdy">
    <div style="background-image: url('http://localhost:5520/Images/certi3.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: medium solid #000000; z-index: 1; top: 64px; position: absolute; height: 474px; width: 674px; left: 177px">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" forecolor="#99CCFF" text="Name" style="z-index: 1; left: 171px; top: 228px; position: absolute; width: 330px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox id="TextBox2" runat="server" text="Date" style="z-index: 1; top: 282px; position: absolute; width: 148px; left: 361px; height: 17px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox id="TextBox3" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 130px; top: 372px; position: absolute; width: 420px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox id="TextBox4" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 227px; top: 282px; position: absolute; width: 62px; height: 17px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:button id="Button1" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; left: 251px; top: 488px; position: absolute; height: 26px" text="Save and Send " onclick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:table id="Table1" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; top: 2px; position: absolute; height: 474px; width: 674px; left: 1px">
    </asp:table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Edit 1: After getting the html layout of aspx page, how could I send and email, with pre-generated html?
following is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{ 
    WebClient myClient = new WebClient(); 
    string myPageHTML = null; 
    byte[] requestHTML; 
    string currentPageUrl = Request.Url.ToString(); 
    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding(); 
    requestHTML = myClient.DownloadData(type the url); 
    myPageHTML = utf8.GetString(requestHTML); 
    Response.Write(myPageHTML); 
    SendMail();
}
```

Comment: Generally such situations are solved with pdf creation. There are plenty of tools available for this task. You may create a pdf file containing the image, data.

Comment: I tried to get the aspx in html format.Now i want to send it as an attachment or body of the mail through email. Here is the code. Please help me with the solution. i have not worked on this before.

Comment: here is the code

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        


        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            
    {
        WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
        string myPageHTML = null;
        byte[] requestHTML;       
  string currentPageUrl = Request.Url.ToString();

        UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        
 requestHTML = myClient.DownloadData(type the url);
myPageHTML = utf8.GetString(requestHTML); 
 Response.Write(myPageHTML);
 SendMail();
                         }

Comment: You want to send the page in ***jpeg*** format? Is it a typo? If it is actually your requirement, you should decompose the problem in smaller parts: 1. how to get a picture of a web content 2. How to send an image in a email. Finally, I agree with @DarshanJoshi, PDF is a good candidate for read only documents.

Comment: As per your comments, now you only need help sending html in email, this article may help you: http://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=6

Comment: FYI, text is better suited to a .gif than a .jpg, you'll get a cleaner smaller image if you go with .gif. .jpg will give lots of 'artificts' (the junky dots you'll see sprinkled around the text).

Answer (score 0):

A bit untradional but you could use a stringbuilder and simply just append your aspx code to the string builder then when sending your MailMessage just add the string builder variable as the body of the mailmessage